# Error al importar chainlink y hacer deploi con brownie

Tags: solidity

```
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

ParserError: Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations:
```

Tengo el siguiente error en el import de chainlink al usar brawnie compile, ya probé varias cosas hasta copie y pege de github y documentacion oficial nada que se soluciona ??
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Coloca los códigos y mensajes de error como texto, no imagen.